# organise dataframe to align rows in r

Tags: r, sorting, alignment, row, reorganize

I have a pretty messy and large dataframe that I need to organize. Ive not been using R for very long so any help will be appreciated.

As an example my dataframe looks something like this:

```
x1 = c("a", "c", "b") 
x2 = c("b", "a", "") 
x3 = c("b", "c", "a") 
df = data.frame(x1, x2, x3)
```

And need to reorganize to align the rows to look like this:

```
x1 = c("a", "b", "c") 
x2 = c("a", "b", "") 
x3 = c("a", "b", "c") 
df = data.frame(x1, x2, x3)
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, x1, x2, and x3 are actually columns. Your original data.frame looks like this:

```
  x1 x2 x3
1  a  b  b
2  c  a  c
3  b     a
```

Are you confusing rows with columns? x1 = c("a", "c", "b") - think of the x1 as the column header or feature and the "a", "c", and "b" are the elements of that column. It can be confusing because you are typing it in across, row wise.

Comment: hi, yes, x1, x2, x3 are column headers and "a" "b" "c" are characters in the dataframe. the "" is to represent some NaNs in the data.

Comment: There is a difference between `"" `and `NA`.  If you want to create a dataframe with NA, you can do so `df = data.frame(x1 = c("a", "c", "b") , x2 = c("b", "a", NA) , x3 = c("b", "c", "a") )`

Answer (score 0):

```
x1 = c("a", "c", "b") 
x2 = c("b", "a", "") 
x3 = c("b", "c", "a") 
df = data.frame(x1, x2, x3)

library(dplyr)

# function that orders non blank values and then adds blanks (if they exist)
f = function(x) c(sort(x[x!=""]), x[x==""])

# apply function to each column using character columns/variables
df %>% mutate_all(~f(as.character(.)))

#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  a  a  a
# 2  b  b  b
# 3  c     c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
x1 = c("a", "c", "b") 
x2 = c("b", "a", "") 
x3 = c("b", "c", "a") 
df = data.frame(x1, x2, x3)
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {
  res <- as.character(x)
  res[res == ""] <- NA
  res <- sort(res, na.last = TRUE)
  res[is.na(res)] <- ""
  res <- as.factor(res)
  res
}))
```